# Different CSS files for different Layouts how to precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want different CSS files for different Layouts.

For example:

app/layouts/application.html.erb would have application.css

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

and app/layouts/admin.html.erb will have admin.css:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin' %>
```

Problem is that the admin.css is not precompiled when I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

What can I do that the admin.css is also precompiled?

I'm using Rails 4.2

EDIT

admin.css file

```
/*
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require filechooser
//= require bootstrap-switch.min
//= require jquery.datetimepicker
//= require fancybox2_1_5/jquery.fancybox
//= require blubb
*= require_self
```

But onlye the code of the blubb.css file is added in admin.css ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In initializers/assets.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(admin.css)
```

Comment: it's not working properly ... added my css which should precompile above

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess the file you put it should be initializers/assets.rb 
You have in the file comments some example already. 
If it's not working, I guess the problem is not so trivial.

Comment: Ah with your edit now I see it more clear! Your asset is precompiled but not all files are included ! Did you try to remove the `//` in front of each, and instead just =require xxxx for each file? And is it working in development mode?